# Valuations of root group elements appearing in the intersection of Iwasawa and Cartan double cosets

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, buildings

$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}
\newcommand{\val}{\mathit{val}}$Let $F$ be a local non-Archimedean field with valuation $\val$ and $G$ be (the
$F$-points of) a split
connected reductive group over $F$. Let $T$ be a split maximal torus and $B$ a
Borel containing $T$ with unipotent radical $U$. Let $K$ be a special parahoric
subgroup of $G$ in good position relative to $(T,U)$. Let $X^*(T)$ be the
lattice of $F$-characters of $T$, which contains the root system $\Phi =
\Phi(G,T)$; let $X_*(T)$ be the $F$-cocharacters of $T$. The choice of $B$
defines a choice of positive roots $\Phi^+$. Let $X_*(T)^+ = \{ \lambda\in
X_*(T)\mid \langle \alpha, \lambda\rangle \ge 0\text{ for all $\alpha\in
\Phi^+$}\}$ be the cocharacters contained in the dominant Weyl chamber.

The Cartan decomposition gives a bijective map 
$$
X_*(T)^+\cong K\backslash G/K
$$
given by $\lambda \mapsto K\lambda(\pi^{-1}) K$, where $\pi$ is a uniformizer in
$F$. The Iwasawa decomposition gives a bijective map 
$$
X_*(T)\cong U\backslash G/K
$$
given by $\mu\mapsto U\mu(\pi^{-1})K$.

I am interested in what happens when $K\lambda(\pi^{-1})K\cap U\mu(\pi^{-1})K
\neq \varnothing$. What is well-known is that $\lambda -\mu$ is a sum of
positive coroots.

> My question is: 
>     What can be said about the $u\in U$ with $u\mu(\pi^{-1}) \in K \lambda(\pi^{-1})K$?

More precisely, the root groups $U_\alpha$, associated to $\alpha\in \Phi$,
carry a valuation $\varphi_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\setminus\{1\} \to \mathbb R$
such that $\varphi = (\varphi_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\Phi}$ is a discrete and special
valuation (in the sense of Bruhat–Tits) on the root group datum
$(T,(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \Phi})$ on $G$ that is compatible with the valuation
on $F$. Writing $u = u_{\alpha_1}\dotsm u_{\alpha_r}$ with $\alpha_i\in \Phi^+$,
do we get a lower bound for $\varphi_{\alpha_i}(u_{\alpha_i})$?

---

Here are my thoughts on this problem, so far:

If $\Phi$ is irreducible and $\alpha_0$ is its highest root (with respect to
$\Phi^+$), I suspect that 
$$
\varphi_{\alpha_i}(u_{\alpha_i}) \ge -\langle
\alpha_0, \lambda\rangle, \quad \text{for all $i$.}
$$
This is not too hard to verify for
$\GL_n(F)$. [There, in fact, we even have $\val(u_{\alpha_{ij}}) \ge -m_j$,
where $\mu(\pi^{-1}) = \diag(\pi^{m_1},\dotsc, \pi^{m_n})$, where we identify
the root group $U_{\alpha_{ij}}$, sitting in the $(i,j)$-th spot, with
$F$.]

One can get a more precise estimate in the case $u\in U_\alpha$ as follows: We
may assume $\varphi_\alpha(u) < \min\{0, -\langle \alpha,\mu\rangle\}$ for
otherwise we would have $u\in K$ or $\mu(\pi^{-1})^{-1}u\mu(\pi^{-1}) \in K$ in
which case $\mu$ lies in the $W$-orbit of $\lambda$. There exist (unique)
$u',u''\in U_{-\alpha}$ such that $u'uu''$ normalizes $T$. [Geometrically,
$u'uu''$ is the reflection (in the apartment corresponding to $T$) in the
hyperplane bounding the half-apartment fixed by $u$.] We have
$\varphi_{-\alpha}(u') = \varphi_{-\alpha}(u'') = -\varphi_{\alpha}(u)$ and
hence $\mu(\pi^{-1})^{-1}u''\mu(\pi^{-1}) \in K$. Thus, we may replace
$u\mu(\pi^{-1})$ by $u'uu'' \mu(\pi^{-1})$ without changing either of the double
cosets. Computing inside the apartment (with the valuation
$\varphi$ taken as the origin), we see that 
$$
u'uu''\mu(\pi^{-1})(\varphi) = \varphi + \mu(\pi^{-1}) - (\langle \alpha,
\mu\rangle + \varphi_\alpha(u))\alpha^\vee
$$
lies inside the convex hull of the $W$-orbit of $\lambda(\pi^{-1})(\varphi)$.
From this, we deduce $-\langle \alpha,\mu\rangle -2\varphi_\alpha(u) = \langle
\alpha, \mu(\pi^{-1}) - (\langle \alpha,\mu\rangle + \varphi_\alpha(u))
\alpha^\vee\rangle \le \langle \alpha_0,\lambda\rangle$ and hence
$$
\varphi_\alpha(u) \ge -\frac{\langle \alpha_0,\lambda\rangle + \langle \alpha,
\mu\rangle}{2}.
$$
Unfortunately, I was unable to generalize this argument to arbitrary $u\in U$,
because the occuring commutators (possibly) destroy any information of the
$u_{\alpha}$'s.

Comment: Although I'm not up to these computations right now, this seems like an interesting question.  I fixed the spurious line break at the beginning; although it seems like good TeX style, you shouldn't leave a blank line between the `$` ending your definitions and the start of your question body.  I think you mean to identify $U_{\alpha_{ij}}$ for $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ with $F$, not $F^\times$, but didn't change it in case I was missing your point.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out. I indeed meant to identify $U_{\alpha_{ij}}$ with $F$.